# Cannot implicit convert a type

Tags: c#, delegates

I am running into a road block when I am trying to do some testing on delegate. My goal is to create instances of `MyStates` class that have the ability to call some predefined functions that I defined in `MyFunctions` class. In the class, I have a dictionary that will refer the functions by name and have a function that retrieve the address of the function and put it in `MyState` instance so that I could refer it at run time. The idea appears to be simple but the compiler is not happy about it. I think I may have an idea of what is wrong but I am not sure how to get rid of the compiler error. Please advise how to fix this compiler error.

`MyFunctions` class is defined as below:

```
public sealed class MyFunctions
{
    public delegate int myFunction(object o);
    private static Dictionary<string, myFunction> funcRouter 
     = new Dictionary<string, myFunction>();
    #region Singleton
    private static readonly MyFunctions _functionInstance = new MyFunctions();
    static MyFunctions()
    {

    }
    private MyFunctions()
    {
        funcRouter.Add("Test2", Test2);
    }
    public static MyFunctions functionInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return _functionInstance;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Definition and implementation of all the functions
    public int Test2(object o)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Testing 2, object received {0}", (int)o);
        return 112;
    }
    #endregion

    public myFunction Get(string s)
    {
        return (myFunction)funcRouter[s];
    }

}
```

`MyStates` class is defined below:

```
public delegate int myFunction(object o);
public class MyState
{
    private int _ID;
    private myFunction _func;

    public myFunction func
    {
        get { return _func; }
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
    }
    public MyState(int myID, myFunction f = null)
    {
        _ID = myID;
        _func = f;
    }

}
```

My main program:

```
public delegate int myFunction(object o);
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myFunction f = null;
        //f = MyFunctions.functionInstance.Test2;
        f = MyFunctions.functionInstance.Get("Test2");
        MyState s = new MyState(123,f);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Note: The code above will generate the compiling error. However, if I use the statement

```
f = MyFunctions.functionInstance.Test2;
```

The program will compile fine and execute correctly. I think the issue resides in the use of dictionary to retrieve the address of the function. It is possible to possible to do that in C++, I would think C# should allow me to do the same thing. I just did not do it correctly.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `public delegate int myFunction(object o);` in two places. The compiler error error says you can't convert one to the other. This is because in the case of `f = MyFunctions.functionInstance.Get("Test2");` you are assigning a return value of one type to a variable of a different type, but with `f = MyFunctions.functionInstance.Test2;` the compiler just looks for a method signature that matches the delegate.

One fix is to declare `f` as `MyDelegates.MyFunctions.myFunction`.

```
MyDelegates.MyFunctions.myFunction f;
f = MyDelegates.MyFunctions.functionInstance.Get("Test2");
```

Another way is to wrap it in your local delegate (because then the signature-match is used again):

```
myFunction f;
f = new myFunction(MyDelegates.MyFunctions.functionInstance.Get("Test2"));
```

The same applies to using it in the `MyState`-call later.

Another way to work around this is to just use `Func<object, int>` everywhere instead of the `myFunction` delegate.

Comment: Ah... that is right! Forgot about Func.. still green with c#...Thanks a bunch!!